# Specifying the column family in Hbase shell command

Tags: hbase

I have a doubt regarding the Hbase shell command.Can we specify the column qualifier during the table creation ie 
If my table name is 'testtable' , column-family is ColumnFamily1 , and qualifiers are 'q1' and 'q2' , can i use the following command to create the table;

create 'testtable' ,'ColumnFamily1:q1' , 'ColumnFamily1:q2'

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify the column qualifiers when you create a table in HBase.  You can simply use create 'testtable', 'ColumnFamily'.

Answer (score 0):

If I may ask, why do you feel the need to declare the column names? You only really need to declare the column family, since issuing a PUT with the `[column family]:[column qualifier]` will "create" the column within the column family for you.

So for now, don't worry about it, since it's taken care of for you. You may want to read through the HBase documentation to get more familiar with how it works, since this is a pretty basic question.